# Change size of dialog by defining height and width in pixels

Tags: c++, dialog, kinect, resource-files

How can I change the size of a dialog box to be 512 x 424 pixels? I know that MapDialogRect() converts from Dialog units to pixels but there is no API to do it in reverse? How will I fix the size of the dialog to what I want in pixels? As I am a beginner in programing, any code would be helpful. Thank you.

This is the resource from the Kinect 2 SDK Depth Basics ,

```
IDD_APP DIALOGEX 0, 0, 512, 436
STYLE  DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Sample"
CLASS "DepthBasicsAppDlgWndClass"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_VIDEOVIEW,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,0,0,512,424
    LTEXT           "",IDC_STATUS,0,425,412,11,SS_SUNKEN,0
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Screenshot",IDC_BUTTON_SCREENSHOT,422,424,90,12
END
```

Comment: Why? Dialogue are sized relative to the font they use so that if the end user scales the UI (eg for accessibility) all the controls display correctly.